# jQuery: too much recursion on .focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using the jQuery `.focus()` method to focus on an element through a remote script in asp.net. I am getting an error about too much recursion.

What am I doing wrong?

asp.net code :

```
Response.Write("<script>$('#ledger_name').focus();</script>");
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="account_name" name="account_name" />
```

js for auto complete

```
$("#account_name").autocomplete({
    source: account_master,
    minLength: 1,
    minChars: 0,
    width: 350,
    mustMatch: 0,
    selectFirst: true,
    matchContains: false,
    autoFocus: true,
    autoFill: false,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#account_name").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#account_name_code").val(ui.item.id);
        $("#account_name_parent").val(ui.item.parent);

        //$('#ledger_name').focus();
        return true;
    }

});
```

jquery ui

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it's giving an error in jquery-ui.min.js file on calling  `$('#ledger_name').focus();` in autocomplete

Comment: I'm guessing you have some more script somewhere which does a `.focus()` and you're in an infinite focus loop of doom. Perhaps post more of your code?

Comment: By itself there is nothing wrong with that script. It's the intended usage and there is no reason it should recur at all. If anything is causing it to recur (why do you think it is? may help us work out the problem), it's because of code elsewhere.

Comment: You already have `autoFocus` set to true on that textbox, so just get rid of the `Response.Write("<script>$('#account_name').focus();</script>");` line in your code behind.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : sorry my mistake .. its not #account_name i want to focus. i want to focus on #ledger_name..

Answer (score 1):

To have textbox with id of "ledger_name" focused upon page load, just add this JavaScript in your .aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ledger_name").focus();
});
</script>
```

No need to do that from the code behind.

Probably focusing it also triggers the autocomplete, so you can't focus it from within the autocomplete itself.